# Erro de alocação de memória para múltiplos arquivos "terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc' what(): std::bad_alloc" [C++]

Tags: c++, alocação, gerenciamento-de-memória, multiple-file-upload, memory-limit

Estou utilizando um algoritmo classificador pra um projeto de processamento digital de sinais de voz. Esse algoritmo foi desenvolvido para receber todos os sinais de áudio em um único vetor para fazer o processamento, mas estou tendo problemas, pois a quantidade de arquivos que estou trabalhando é muito grande e está gerando o erro "terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
what():  std::bad_alloc". Gostaria de saber se é possível fazer alguma alteração no código que lê os arquivos e os armazena no vetor de forma mais eficiente, sem que ultrapasse o espaço de memória disponível.

Código para leitura dos arquivos:

```
    string filename;
    filename="C:\\Users\\marcu\\Desktop\\TCC\\Arquivos_10780\\Arquivos_DFT_TXT_512\\PA_D_00";

    std::vector<double> c;

    for(int j=1; j<=5400; j++)
    {
        stringstream ss;
        ss << filename << setw(5) << setfill('0') << j << "_bonafide_DFT.txt";

        std::ifstream f;
        f.open(ss.str().c_str());

        if (f.is_open())
        {
            double num;

            while (f >> num)
                c.push_back(num);

            f.close();
        }
        else
        {
            f.close();
            continue;
        }
    }

    for(int j=5401; j<=29700; j++)
    {
        stringstream ss;
        ss << filename << setw(5) << setfill('0') << j << "_spoof_DFT.txt";

        std::ifstream f;
        f.open(ss.str().c_str());

        if (f.is_open())
        {
            double num;

            while (f >> num)
                c.push_back(num);

            f.close();
        }
        else
        {
            f.close();
            continue;
        }
    }
```

Código completo:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
#include<vector>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<iomanip>
#include<sstream>

using namespace std;

double mean_similarities(double**,int,int);//vectors, number of vectors, their dimension

int main()
{
    const int number_of_classes=2;
    int number_of_feature_vectors_in_class[number_of_classes];
    number_of_feature_vectors_in_class[0]=2700;
    number_of_feature_vectors_in_class[1]=8080;
    const int dimension_of_each_feature_vector=512;

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/*
Example: 3 classes and 4 vectors of dimension 2 in each class
{{0.90,0.12},{0.88,0.14},{0.88,0.13},{0.89,0.11}}   //0.88---0.90 ; 0.11---0.14
{{0.55,0.53},{0.53,0.55},{0.54,0.54},{0.56,0.54}}   //0.53---0.56 ; 0.53---0.55
{{0.10,0.88},{0.11,0.86},{0.12,0.87},{0.11,0.88}}   //0.10---0.12 ; 0.86---0.88  

double c[]={ 
0.90,0.12,0.88,0.14,0.88,0.13,0.89,0.11,
0.55,0.53,0.53,0.55,0.54,0.54,0.56,0.54,
0.10,0.88,0.11,0.86,0.12,0.87,0.11,0.88
//all vectors in class C_1, followed by all vectors in C_2, ...., followed by all in C_n
            };
*/
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    string filename;
    filename="C:\\Users\\marcu\\Desktop\\TCC\\Arquivos_10780\\Arquivos_DFT_TXT_512\\PA_D_00";

    std::vector<double> c;

    for(int j=1; j<=5400; j++)
    {
        stringstream ss;
        ss << filename << setw(5) << setfill('0') << j << "_bonafide_DFT.txt";

        std::ifstream f;
        f.open(ss.str().c_str());

        if (f.is_open())
        {
            double num;

            while (f >> num)
                c.push_back(num);

            f.close();
        }
        else
        {
            f.close();
            continue;
        }
    }

    for(int j=5401; j<=29700; j++)
    {
        stringstream ss;
        ss << filename << setw(5) << setfill('0') << j << "_spoof_DFT.txt";

        std::ifstream f;
        f.open(ss.str().c_str());

        if (f.is_open())
        {
            double num;

            while (f >> num)
                c.push_back(num);

            f.close();
        }
        else
        {
            f.close();
            continue;
        }
    }

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//edit whatever you need, according to the feature vectors of your problem, ABOVE this line.
//Do NOT change anything BELOW this line !!!!!
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    double*** C=new double**[number_of_classes];
    for(int i=0; i<number_of_classes; i++)
        C[i]=new double*[number_of_feature_vectors_in_class[i]];
    for(int i=0; i<number_of_classes; i++)
        for(int j=0; j<number_of_feature_vectors_in_class[i]; j++)
            C[i][j]=new double[dimension_of_each_feature_vector];
    int l=0;
    for(int i=0; i<number_of_classes; i++)
        for(int j=0; j<number_of_feature_vectors_in_class[i]; j++)
            for(int k=0; k<dimension_of_each_feature_vector; k++)
            {
                C[i][j][k]=c[l];
                l++;
            }

//Debug info only
//for(int i=0;i<number_of_classes;i++)
//  for(int j=0;j<number_of_feature_vectors_in_class[i];j++)
//      for(int k=0;k<dimension_of_each_feature_vector;k++)
//          printf("\nclass %d vector %d element %d is %.3f",i,j,k,C[i][j][k]);
//getchar();
    double Y[number_of_classes];
    for(int i=0; i<number_of_classes; i++)
        Y[i]=mean_similarities(C[i],number_of_feature_vectors_in_class[i],dimension_of_each_feature_vector);
    double alpha=Y[0];
    for(int i=1; i<number_of_classes; i++)
        if(Y[i]<alpha)
            alpha=Y[i];
    printf("\nALPHA: %.3f",alpha);
    double** smallest_range_vector_for_class=new double*[number_of_classes];
    for(int i=0; i<number_of_classes; i++)
        smallest_range_vector_for_class[i]=new double[dimension_of_each_feature_vector];
    for(int i=0; i<number_of_classes; i++)
        for(int k=0; k<dimension_of_each_feature_vector; k++)
            smallest_range_vector_for_class[i][k]=C[i][0][k];
    for(int i=0; i<number_of_classes; i++)
        for(int j=1; j<number_of_feature_vectors_in_class[i]; j++)
            for(int k=0; k<dimension_of_each_feature_vector; k++)
                if(C[i][j][k]<smallest_range_vector_for_class[i][k])
                    smallest_range_vector_for_class[i][k]=C[i][j][k];

//Debug info only
//for(int i=0;i<number_of_classes;i++)
//  for(int k=0;k<dimension_of_each_feature_vector;k++)
//          printf("\nclass %d smallest component %d is %.3f",i,k,smallest_range_vector_for_class[i][k]);
    double** largest_range_vector_for_class=new double*[number_of_classes];
    for(int i=0; i<number_of_classes; i++)
        largest_range_vector_for_class[i]=new double[dimension_of_each_feature_vector];
    for(int i=0; i<number_of_classes; i++)
        for(int k=0; k<dimension_of_each_feature_vector; k++)
            largest_range_vector_for_class[i][k]=C[i][0][k];
    for(int i=0; i<number_of_classes; i++)
        for(int j=1; j<number_of_feature_vectors_in_class[i]; j++)
            for(int k=0; k<dimension_of_each_feature_vector; k++)
                if(C[i][j][k]>largest_range_vector_for_class[i][k])
                    largest_range_vector_for_class[i][k]=C[i][j][k];

//Debug info only
//for(int i=0;i<number_of_classes;i++)
//  for(int k=0;k<dimension_of_each_feature_vector;k++)
//          printf("\nclass %d largest component %d is %.3f",i,k,largest_range_vector_for_class[i][k]);
    int R=0;
    int F=0;
    for(int ia=0; ia<number_of_classes; ia++)
        for(int ib=0; ib<number_of_classes; ib++)
            for(int j=0; j<number_of_feature_vectors_in_class[ib]; j++)
                for(int k=0; k<dimension_of_each_feature_vector; k++)
                {
                    if(ib!=ia)
                    {
                        if((C[ib][j][k]>smallest_range_vector_for_class[ia][k])&&(C[ib][j][k]<largest_range_vector_for_class[ia][k]))
                            R++;
                        F++;
                    }
                }
    double beta=((double)(R))/((double)(F));
    printf("\nBETA: %.3f",beta);
    printf("\nP=(G1,G2)=(%.3f,%.3f)",alpha-beta,alpha+beta-1);
    printf("\nDistance from P to (1,0): %.3f",sqrt(pow((alpha-beta)-1,2)+pow(alpha+beta-1,2)));
    printf("\n\n");
}
/////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////
double mean_similarities(double** v,int n, int t)
{
    double largest;
    double smallest;
    double* s=new double[t];
    for(int i=0; i<t; i++)
    {
        smallest=1;
        largest=0;
        for(int j=0; j<n; j++)
        {
            if(v[j][i]>largest)
                largest=v[j][i];
            if(v[j][i]<smallest)
                smallest=v[j][i];
        }
        s[i]=1-(largest-smallest);
    }
    double m=0;
    for(int i=0; i<t; i++)
        m+=s[i];
    m/=((double)(t));
    return(m);
}
```

PS: para encontrar o melhor resultado do classificador, necessito alterar o tamanho da dimensão dos arquivos (quantidade de informação de cada arquivo) para valores cada vez maiores. A princípio com 512 pontos, mas vou dobrando esse valor a cada execução até chegar em 8192, mas quando tento com 16384 o código trava. Estou trabalhando com 10780 arquivos onde cada um tem a mesma dimensão e vou amentando conforme vou verificando o resultado.

Comment: Quanto de memória vc espera que o programa use? Se for muito implementar um alocador customizado pode ser uma boa ideia.

Comment: vc recomenda alguma documentação ou biblioteca que eu possa ver para implementar?

Answer (score 0):

Algo fácil que você pode tentar é utilizar vetor de floats ao invés de vetor de doubles para armazenar os valores. Isso vai cortar pela metade a memória que seu vetor usa e pode ser que a perda de precisão não seja um grande problema no seu caso.

Outro ponto importante é reservar memória para o vetor antes de fazer o `push_back` utilizando `c.reserve(numero_de_elementos)`. Você sabe quantos elementos o vetor vai ter no final? Se sim reserve o espaço **antes** de fazer `push_back`. Cada vez que você faz um `push_back` se a memória atualmente alocada para o vetor não couber o elemento novo então o `std::vector` vai alocar uma **nova** região de memória com o dobro da capacidade da atual (nesse momento seu programa vai estar utilizando o triplo da memória necessária só para esse vetor), copiar os elementos da memória antiga, e então liberar a memória antiga. Se você não reservar memória então esse processo provavelmente vai acontecer várias vezes a medida que você utiliza `push_back`.

Além disso, mesmo que você possua memória livre para que possa utilizar o triplo do que precisa, pode ser que sua memória livre esteja distribuída e não seja possível alocar uma região contínua de memória durante esse processo de realocação do `std::vector` se o vetor tiver muitos elementos.

Comment: Utilizei .reserve, mas ainda estou tendo estouro de memória no meio do processo. Fazendo alguns testes, vi que o processamento foi mais adiante do que antes, mas ainda é insuficiente. Num outro comentário falaram sobre um alocador customizado, vc sabe algo sobre??

Comment: Se não me engano a motivação para utilizar alocador customizado normalmente é para desempenho, quando você faz muitas alocações, mas nunca utilizei um. Não sei se ele realmente ajudaria no seu caso. Quando você fez o reserve você tem certeza que reservou para o número de elementos que o vetor vai ter no final e não algum valor menor?

Comment: Me corrija se eu estiver errado. Estou fazendo a leitura de 10780 arquivos com 16384 elementos cada. Nesse caso, preciso fazer a alocação de 10780 * 16384 = 176619520 ou preciso de mais espaço?

Comment: No meio do código, tem um comentário com "Do NOT change anything BELOW this line !!!!!" Isso é do desenvolvedor do algoritmo, mas se vc tiver algum dica que possa tratar melhor as etapas seguintes do código sem que altere o resultado, tbm ajudaria

Comment: Você precisa processar todos os arquivos juntos? Não poderia processar um arquivo de cada vez? Ou um grupo de arquivos de cada vez? Além disso, o "código que não deve ser mudado" contém vários "new"s e não tem nenhum delete (assim como a função `mean_similarities`). Quem é que deve cuidar de deletar toda essa memória alocada com tantos "new"s? É uma boa ideia tentar usar esse gerenciamento manual de memória e trocar por `unique_ptr`, por exemplo.